# Java Swing.Timer get real time millisecond

Tags: java, swing, javax.swing.timer

I'm having a problem in my program. I want to get a real time millisecond that equal to 1000 in 1 seconds. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

class lsen implements ActionListener{
    int ms = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int m = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        this.ms++;

        if(this.ms == 500){
            this.s++;
            this.ms = 0;
        }
        if(this.s == 60){
            this.m++;
            this.s = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getMS(){
        return this.ms;
    }
    public int getSS(){
        return this.s;
    }
    public int getMM(){
        return this.m;
    }
}

public class stopwatch_main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lsen l = new lsen();
        Timer t = new Timer(0,l);
        t. start();
        while(true){
            System.out.println(l.getMM()+":"+l.getSS()+":"+l.getMS());
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way in getting the millisecond rather than declaring a integer and incrementing it?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, your intention is to let the `actionPerformed` method be called 1000 times per second, namely exactly every millisecond. This will hardly be possible. You might come close to it with an own thread and *busy waiting*, but even then it will be hard. ("Busy waiting" here indeed refers to an unthrottled `while(true)` loop - that's the closest to "real time" that you can get in Java, but you should hardly ever have to do this...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You will want to get rid of that `while (true)` and instead use the Swing Timer in its place since that is what the Timer is for -- to repeatedly make calls in a Swing GUI **without** having to resort to a thread-breaking `while (true)` construct.
2. You will want to give your Timer a reasonable delay time. 0? Common sense tells you not to use this. 12, 15 -- better.
3. For a Swing Timer to work, you need to have an active Swing event thread, and this can be obtained by showing a Swing GUI, any GUI such as a JOptionPane.

   ---

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Lsen implements ActionListener {
   public static final int MSECS_PER_SEC = 1000;
   public static final int SECS_PER_MIN = 60;
   public static final int MIN_PER_HR = 60;
   private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d";

   private long startTime;
   private JTextField timeField;

   public Lsen(JTextField timeField) {
      this.timeField = timeField;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (startTime == 0L) {
         startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      } else {
         long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         int diffTime = (int) (currentTime - startTime);

         int mSecs = diffTime % MSECS_PER_SEC;
         diffTime /= MSECS_PER_SEC;

         int sec = diffTime % SECS_PER_MIN;
         diffTime /= SECS_PER_MIN;

         int min = diffTime % MIN_PER_HR;
         diffTime /= MIN_PER_HR;

         int hours = diffTime;

         String time = String.format(TIME_FORMAT, hours, min, sec, mSecs);
         // System.out.println("Time: " + time);
         timeField.setText(time);
      }
   }
}

public class StopWatchMain {
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 15;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JTextField timeField = new JTextField(10);
      timeField.setEditable(false);
      timeField.setFocusable(false);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(new JLabel("Elapsed Time:"));
      panel.add(timeField);

      Lsen l = new Lsen(timeField);
      Timer t = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, l);
      t.start();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
      t.stop();
   }
}
```

---

**Edit**
You ask about the meaning of the long data type. Please have a look here: [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). You'll see that long means long integer, and so you can think of it as being similar to int but able to tolerate much larger positive and negative values without overflowing.

Comment: thank you! this is so helpful i will analyze the code later :)

Comment: what is the use of difftime? and i can't understand the calculation in long. can i ask for any reference regarding a long datatype? it very new to me

Comment: @AdrianManuelCleofe: see edit to answer and the link it contains.