# Why is my button not clickable? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I have a java swing gui program and when I click a toggle button a timer begins but I want to be able to click the same button and the timer stops and right now it won't let me click on it again.
This is in my timer class

```
 public void runningClock(){
      isPaused = false;
      while(!isPaused){
      incrementTime();
      System.out.println("Timer Current Time " + getTime());
      time.setText(""+ getTime());  
      try{Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(Exception e){}
      }
  }


public void pausedClock(){
        isPaused=true;
        System.out.println("Timer Current Time " + getTime());
        time.setText(""+ getTime());
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(Exception e){}
   }
```

and this is in my main class

```
private void btnRunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    if(btnRun.getText().equals("Run")){
          System.out.println("Run Button Clicked");
          btnRun.setText("Pause");
          test.runningClock();
    }
    else if(btnRun.getText().equals("Pause")){
        System.out.println("Pause Button Clicked");
        btnRun.setText("Run");
        test.pausedClock();

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the cause of the problem and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a away to fix it (as has already been mentioned)

Answer (score 5):

You're freezing the Swing event thread with your `Thread.sleep(...)` and `while (something)` loops. Solution: don't do that -- don't call code on the event thread that occupies the event thread and prevents it from doing its necessary tasks. Instead change the ***state*** of your program. And for your clock, use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).  For example, please look at my answer and code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25592738/522444).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in your program, `try{Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(Exception e){}`. As this statement is applied on the main thread itself, so the application itself hangs or you can say freezes. What you can do is apply a separate thread for the timer.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
              //Do Stuff
         }
 }).start();
```